# Django - Fixtures in XML

Tags: django, django-fixtures

Could anyone points out the docs which describes how the fixture can be done with XML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a `manage.py dumpdata --format=xml --indent=4` and you will see the xml output, which you can also use for loaddata.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, +1 to you Izz!

Answer (score 3):

These two pages should help:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

and

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/serialization/

Comment: I agree, they should help, but all the examples there are dealing with json and yaml, no XML at all. I used the trick provided by Izz's answer to get a view of the xml format to use.